# Mysqld end unexpectedly because of a block of php codes

Tags: php, mysql

I have here a code wherein it populates the dropdown list thru database records.... from different tables as well.

I have several tables wherein 1 table = 1 dropdown list

The code: (showhide_dropdown)

```
<?php 
$hostname = "localhost"; // usually is localhost, but if not sure, 
             check with your hosting company, 
             if you are with webune leave as localhost 
$db_user = "root"; // change to your database password 
$db_password = ""; // change to your database password 
$database = "minquep_test"; // provide your database name 
$db_table1 = "roles"; // leave this as is 
$db_table2 = "companies";
$db_table3 = "albury_branch";
$db_table4 = "minquep_branch";
$db_table5 = "countries";

$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password); 
mysql_select_db($database,$db); 
?> 

<?php
$roles_sql="SELECT role_id, role_name FROM $db_table1";
$comp_sql= "SELECT company_name FROM $db_table2";
$albury_sql= "SELECT albury_id, albury_name FROM $db_table3";
$minq_sql= "SELECT minquep_id, minquep_name FROM $db_table4"; 
$count_sql= "SELECT country_id, country_name FROM $db_table5"; 

$roles_result=mysql_query($roles_sql); 
$comp_result=mysql_query($comp_sql); 
$al_result=mysql_query($albury_sql); 
$minq_result=mysql_query($minq_sql);
$count_result=mysql_query($count_sql);

$roles_options=""; 
$comp_options="";
$al_options="";
$minq_options="";
$count_options="";

while ($roles_row=mysql_fetch_array($roles_result)) { 

    $roles_id=$roles_row["role_id"]; 
    $role=$roles_row["role_name"]; 
    $roles_options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$role\">".$role; 
} 

while ($comp_row=mysql_fetch_array($comp_result)) { 

    $company=$comp_row["company_name"]; 
    $comp_options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$company\">".$company; 
} 

while ($al_row=mysql_fetch_array($al_result)) { 

    $albury=$al_row["albury_name"]; 
    $al_options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$albury\">".$albury;
} 

while ($minq_row=mysql_fetch_array($minq_result)) { 

    $minquep=$minq_row["minquep_name"]; 
    $minq_options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$minquep\">".$minquep;
} 

while ($count_row=mysql_fetch_array($count_result)) { 

    $country=$count_row["country_name"]; 
    $count_options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$country\">".$country;
} 


?>
```

At first, it really works just fine but then when I open the page wherein this code was posted... a mysql.exe error message would just suddenly pop up (The normal Microsoft error) says: Unexpected error... something like that.

And then a mysql error/warning will be displayed on my page..

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result 
         resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\minquep-native\pages\showhide_dropdown.php 
         on line 60
```

I dont understand the problem. I'm new to PHP please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems with this query :

```
SELECT country_id, country_name FROM countries
```

Make sure that the columns and the table does exist (try to execute the query directly in mysql and see what you get). The error you are getting is because the query could not be executed.

Comment: Thanks. I have another issue right now. My phpmyadmin is still access denied. Tsk. Thanks again. Probably it the countries table was not existing. But I saw it the last time I ran my program... Its really weird.

Answer (score 0):

So the error you are getting is a symptom of an earlier error:

At line 60 you do something like this:

```
while ($comp_row=mysql_fetch_array($comp_result)) {
```

[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) requires a mysql result object. However it has gotten something else (False actually). The reason it has gotten something else is because this line:

```
$comp_result=mysql_query($comp_sql);
```

Gave back False rather than a Mysql result, change this:

```
$roles_result=mysql_query($roles_sql); 
$comp_result=mysql_query($comp_sql); 
$al_result=mysql_query($albury_sql); 
$minq_result=mysql_query($minq_sql);
$count_result=mysql_query($count_sql);
```

to:

```
$roles_result=mysql_query($roles_sql); 
if(mysql_errno() != 0) echo mysql_error();
$comp_result=mysql_query($comp_sql); 
if(mysql_errno() != 0) echo mysql_error();
$al_result=mysql_query($albury_sql); 
if(mysql_errno() != 0) echo mysql_error();
$minq_result=mysql_query($minq_sql);
if(mysql_errno() != 0) echo mysql_error();
$count_result=mysql_query($count_sql);
if(mysql_errno() != 0) echo mysql_error();
```

To see what error has occured.

Note:

If you use a framework like Laravel or any other, it'll catch these error's for you. Also I'd use mysqli not mysql since mysql is outdated, see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php